# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello only admin/ path is defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

i am following the django instructions to build a web application hello
i have done everthing after the document but this happens
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
Using the URLconf defined in PythonWeb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, hello, didn’t match any of these.
there must be another path as hello/

this is my code:
views.py/hello:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello.")
```

urls.py/pythonweb(my app):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls'))
]
```

urls.py/hello:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name =('index'))
]
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello',
]
```

Comment: Please remove `django-forms` tag and write `django-views` tag instead because your question is related to `views` and not `forms`. I will try to find out what's wrong and post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a silly mistake in `settings.py` file:

Remove `/` after `hello`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello',
]
```

Comment: i've edited it but it's still not working

Comment: I don't know if your solution will solve the issue as I didn't try it. However, it is recommended to write `hello.apps.HelloConfig` instead of only `hello`.

Comment: @Jafoor still 404

Comment: @Ambitions where should i change it

Comment: @hoànghuy in `settings.py`, the same place that you wrote `hello/` then you changed it to `hello`.

Comment: @Ambitions it should work on both `hello` or `hello.apps.HelloConfig`. There may be other problems.
@hoànghuy can you please create a new app deleting this hello app with another name? I wish that would work.

Comment: @Jafoor I know. I mentioned that it doesn't matter. However, it is recommended to write it as `hello.apps.HelloConfig`. Please see `Django` documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps. It is written that it is preferred to link to an application configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me. I did two edits which are:

**settings.py:**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello.apps.HelloConfig',
]
```

Please note that your problem is not with `settings.py`, my edit will not make any difference. However, it is recommended to write it this way `hello.apps.HelloConfig`.

Also, I edited `hello/urls.py`, I removed the redundant parenthesis

**hello/urls.py:**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Please let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: it's still nor working. i dont think the problem comes from my code